# TypeLoadException on startup

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

Recently started using Xamarin and MvvmCross. Busy building my first project. Created my .Core project and a ViewModel, installed the Nuget package in Visual Studio. Created my .Droid project, installed Nuget package. Created my first views and now trying to run the application. I however get the following exception:

```
Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid'.

Full stacktrace:
W/        ( 1438): Missing method .ctor in assembly /data/data/XamTest.Droid/files/.__override__/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.dll, type System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute
W/        ( 1438): Can't find custom attr constructor image: /data/data/XamTest.Droid/files/.__override__/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid.dll mtoken: 0x0a000012
Unhandled Exception:

System.TypeLoadException: 
E/mono    ( 1438): 
E/mono    ( 1438): Unhandled Exception:
E/mono    ( 1438): System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid'.
E/mono    ( 1438): at XamTest.Droid.SplashScreen..ctor () [0x00000] in c:\Dev\XamTest\XamTest.Droid\SplashScreen.cs:16
E/mono    ( 1438): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.38e61b4f-1913-46a5-ba4a-75980457a823 (intptr,object[]) <IL 0x00018, 0x00053>
E/mono    ( 1438): at Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0006a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bigsplash/0e0e51f9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Interop/TypeManager.cs:141
E/mono    ( 1438): at (wrapper native-to-managed) Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0001e, 0x000a3>
E/mono    ( 1438): 
I/mono    ( 1438): [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ExtensionAttribute' from assembly 'Cirrious.MvvmCross.Droid'.
I/mono    ( 1438): at XamTest.Droid.SplashScreen..ctor () [0x00000] in c:\Dev\XamTest\XamTest.Droid\SplashScreen.cs:16
I/mono    ( 1438): at (wrapper dynamic-method) object.38e61b4f-1913-46a5-ba4a-75980457a823 (intptr,object[]) <IL 0x00018, 0x00053>
I/mono    ( 1438): at Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x0006a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-lion-bigsplash/0e0e51f9/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Java.Interop/TypeManager.cs:141
I/mono    ( 1438): at (wrapper native-to-managed) Java.Interop.TypeManager.n_Activate (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr) <IL 0x0001e, 0x000a3>
I/mono    ( 1438):
```

Any ideas?

I need to mention that when I open my solution in Xamarin.Studio the reference to the Core library shows up as an error.

> (- Incompatible target framework (.Net Portable Subset (.Net for Windows Store, .Net Framework 4.5, Silverlight 4, Windows Phone 7.5).).

This might just be another problem though, and not related to the exception.

Comment: Updated to include the full stacktrace.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me when I had this exact same issue:

When I updated mvvmCross I still used an older version of Xamarin, which used an older version of monodroid. Updating Xamarin (new version uses monodroid 3) fixed the issue for me.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the version of the Hot Tuna Starter pack I installed. I installed version 3.0.12.

When I replaced the Cirrious.MVVM and Cirrious.MVVM.Droid dll's located at packages\MvvmCross.HotTuna.MvvmCrossLibraries.3.0.12\lib\MonoAndroid16 with the dll's from the Hot Tuna Starter pack V3.0.9 everything started working fine. (I also tested 3.0.4 which worked fine too)

I did not test V3.0.10 and v3.0.11. I also tested v 3.0.13 BETA, but it is still broken.

Comment: The main difference v3.0.9 to today is the change in xamarin.android version - to the new one that uses mono3 - this is 'stable' from xamarin. What xamarin release are you using?

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you using Visual Studio 2012 and Xamarin latest from the stable branch?
2. **Important**: In Visual Studio, make sure you have latest NuGet manager by going to Tools menu \ Extensions and Updates \ Updates tab on the left.
3. I suggest you start over with a new test project and follow Exactly these steps:

   a) Create a new Android app called MyApp.Droid, and a new PCL project MyApp.Core (target '.NET Framework 4.5' and 'Windows Phone 7.5 and above' - **these are the minimum framework versions which MVVMCross works with**)

   b) Add the MyApp.Core as project reference to MyApp.Droid

   c) Using NuGet, install 'MVVMCross Hot Tuna Starter Pack'. Make sure you have stable branch selected (there's a combobox at the top of the NuGet window)

   Everything should compile and run fine.

Comment: Thank you OpCoder. Those are the exact steps I followed, but as someone else put it "There be dragons in your PC". I finally resolved it by replacing the Cirrious binaries with an older version (Not the 3.0.12 version currently being installed by the Hot Tuna Starter pack).

Comment: there is no reason to put an older version. you should use the last stable one. you were targeting the wrong frameworks